# Should I use empirical or distribution-estimated quantiles for N=50?

Tags: bayesian, inference, fitting, curve-fitting, interpolation

I am building a custom value-at-risk platform at my job but have only 50 samples from which to draw. Because the stakeholders want to run the analysis for arbitrary confidence levels (not just ones in multiples of 1/50 = 0.02), I am fitting the data to various statistical distributions, and then the program will spit out the theoretical value corresponding to any user-specified quantile.

While I understand that the KS test is sometimes used to compare a theoretical distribution to observed values, I have read that the KS test performs poorly with extreme values, leading to potentially erroneous conclusions. For that reason, I have resorted to comparing the empirical quantiles of my sample data to the theoretical quantiles of distributions fitted to the sample data, and then identifying the distribution that minimizes the sum of square errors between the two.

Is this a reasonable approach? I feel that this should reasonably capture the shape of the distribution and offer reasonable results, but a) the approach offers only relative goodness of fit (to what extent a distribution outperforms the others when fitting the data) but says nothing about whether the data do in fact come from that distribution; and b) I wonder to what extent the observed data actually represent the underlying process.

A final alternative that crossed my mind is to interpolate "missing" quantiles with cubic splines, but then I also don't know to which quantile the minimum value in the empirical data actually corresponds.

What should I do? Am I on the right path by fitting the data and simply selecting the best overall fit based on quantiles? Or should I just resort to the KS test and accept its drawbacks? Or should I assume that the empirical quantiles are representative of the true distribution and then interpolate "missing" quantiles?

Thank you for your assistance; I greatly appreciate your time and input!

Comment: +1 but an issue with your approach is that you have the perfect distribution to minimize that difference...the empirical distribution! So then you try to fit an exponential distribution with a rate parameter derived from the data, a normal with mean and variance derived from the data, etc, and you would have an argument for why one of your selected distributions fits the data better than the others, but you’ve hardly exhausted all possible distributions, just the common ones. Then when you start doing uncommon distributions, those are limitless...and you still have the perfect distribution!

Comment: Thank you for your input Dave! But how can I determine quantiles outside of those in the original data? And how would I know to which quantile the minimum (or, for that matter, the maximum) of the empirical data really corresponds? I also wouldn't be able to do 99% confidence or 99.9% confidence by using the empirical data, as the minimum observed value is ~25 but can theoretically go to zero. As you said, though, I have had to resort to more esoteric distributions (e.g. Nakagami, Fold Cauchy, Half Cauchy, Rice, Burr and several others) in my quest to find the "best fit" ... it's an adventure.

Comment: The software out there does the in-between quantiles. Perhaps look into how R’s “quantile” function works for that. Python (and I’m sure other languages) has a function to do the same, probably in script.stats, but I do not remember offhand what it is called. Also, there are issues with KS (and similar, like Shapiro-Wilk) testing the fit of data to a theoretical distribution, and Cross Validated generally discourages doing so.

Comment: Thank you again, Dave! I suppose another issue with my approach is aggregating the resulting percentiles. Adding the P(95) of two uncorrelated assets would actually give me a P(99.75) event, since the probability of both assets having a P(95) event is 0.05^2 = 0.0025. Otherwise, assuming the assets are equally weighted, could I just assume that each experiences a P(97.5) event, since 0.95^0.5 ~ 0.975? Sorry to get off-track; I appreciate your insight!

Comment: Stack Exchange works best when distinct questions are posted as distinct questions. If you’re curious about that question, please ask a new question. Consider the quantitative finance Stack, too: quant.stackexchange.com.